Arduino ESP8266 (arduino-esp8266) documentation for core_esp8266_waveform.h
Intro
I have found by chance the following header file in Arduino core library for ESP8266:
core_esp8266_waveform.h
That defines interesting functions like startWaveform that should allow for playing (maybe?) an arbitrary waveform using pwm.
I would like to know more about this library that seems interesting.
What I have tried
I have looked for documentation but I have found only these:
https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.1/
https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
These are documentation of the Arduino ESP8266 platform but there is no trace of the waveform library.
Source files are in the following path:
[framework-arduinoespressif8266 home path]/cores/esp8266
And interesting files are:
core_esp8266_waveform.h
core_esp8266_waveform_phase.cpp
Final question
Beyond trial and error and self studying what the source does (that I will do as a last resort), is there some documentation I was not able to find?

there is not much trial and error to be done ... there are only two functions to try ... one starts the waveform and the other stops the waveform

not sure what exactly you are interested in those functions as there are more abstracted function of tone() and noTone() that achieved the same. It actually the functions used in tone() and noTone() implementation, you can find out more it usage from https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/cores/esp8266/Tone.cpp.

@hcheung
Beyond what can be inferred from the method signature and (maybe) random examples found here and there I would like to build a base knowledge of how these functions are implemented in order to decide if to use some of them or implement on my own.
I'm going to use these devices as waveform generators for a musical project.
If it's not documented then I have to reverse-engineer the code  ...
I find your answer useful.

Please look at Arduino tone() documentation for more details, it might provide the API that you need.

You can try the startWaveform library: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/cores/esp8266/core_esp8266_waveform.h
